# how do i remove \n and \r in from aReadStream text file

Tags: javascript

so i need to get from a text file alot of data and when i use fs.createReadStream and copy the data to a varible and start changing it it looks like \n and \r and present and the are messing my splits and array checking and i tried to do a function that removes them that runs on the array and checks for ''(it doesnt work for some reason)

```
if(arr[i]==='\'(this throws the mistake){**strong text**
(removing it and stuff)
}
```

do you have any idea how to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the String prototype `replaceAll`, or work with split and join:

```
let data = '\r \n sdfsdf. \r'

data = data.replaceAll(`\r`, '')
data = data.replaceAll(`\n`, '')



OR ------------------------

let data = '\r \n sdfsdf. \r'

data = data.split(`\r`).join('').split(`\n`).join()
```

Pay attention - replaceAll is a new prototype and exists only on Node v.15+ and the latest versions of the modern browsers.
See MDN documents to check your needs.